# Is there a verb for 'unconditionally beats or takes priority over'?

Tags: word-choice

Sometimes people use *trump* in this sense.

> Human rights are legal trump cards, you can make whatever laws you want so long as it doesn't violate one.

The relations between rock, paper, and scissors in the handgame also fit what I mean to describe.

Comment: Supersede, maybe.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer

Comment: @ThePopMachine Actually, states may give MORE human rights protections (just no LESS) than the federal system, so what he is discussing is not supercedence or preeminence or subject-matter jurisdiction, but the inviolability of the federal protections (not their 'superiority').

Comment: I don't understand that OP is asking.   The verbs which means "to unconditionally beat or take priority" is "to trump".   I don't know why he is answering his own question in the description or what he means to be asking with those examples.

Comment: @ThePopMachine *Trump* is an analogy to the game of bridge. If you read the dictionary definitions, you won't find a definition that corresponds with uses such as 'Human rights trump x'.

Comment: @Hal:   How exactly do you think that words pick up new "dictionary deifnitions" ?     Human rights trump economic concerns.   The constitution trumps local by-laws.   Anyone would understand this (including, I daresay, from context even if they've never seen the word).   Who cares what your dictionary says?   Furthermore, I would find it very surprising if someone can't find this definition in a dictionary anyhow.

Comment: @Hal Alright, under your constraints I have another suggestion that I have not seen yet although it is not a common use:  preempt 5.
to forestall or prevent (something anticipated) by acting first; preclude; head off: an effort to preempt inflation. "Human rights laws are preemptive; you can make whatever laws you want so long as it doesn't violate one."  Of course, this is the noun form, but there is a verb form as well.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Yes that's how words come to have new meanings. Therefore, I should use words in new and trendy ways? When they become how popular? I suspect I'm more conservative about that then you are.

Comment: @APrejean yeah I think preempt is it.

Comment: @Hal:   This is not new and trendy.   The term trump has apparently existed since 1529.   And see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump#Metaphorical_uses] .    If you don't buy that there is a "dictionary definition" then you still should be okay with a "metaphorical use".

Comment: @Hal: Anyhow -- here is Merriam Webster's definition.  3trump verb: to beat (another card) by playing a card from the suit that beats the other suits : to play a trump card to beat (another card)

: to do better than (someone or something) in a contest, competition, etc.
: to be more important than (something)     ... 2trump noun
1 a :  a card of a suit any of whose cards will win over a card that is not of this suit —called also trump card
b :  the suit whose cards are trumps for a particular hand —often used in plural
2:  a decisive overriding factor or final resource —called also trump card

Comment: Merriam's is reputed for its permissiveness. Here's AHD,  *To take (a card or trick) with a trump.
2. To get the better of (an adversary or competitor, for example) by using a crucial, often hidden resource.* Here's OED (In bridge, whist, and similar card games) play a trump on (a card of another suit) 1.1. Surpass (something) by saying or doing something better* None of those convey what I want to convey. Regardless, as a matter of style, I prefer not to use metaphors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [**prevail**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prevail?s=t) and "supersede."

Other acceptable alternatives are "**override**" and "**overrule**."

Comment: Yeah. Those are close. I hadn't considered them. But, I'm hoping there's something out there that isn't conditional. (E.g. prevail is conditional on the person doing something in order to prevail; override and overrule are conditional on someone deciding to do so, ditto for words like 'veto' - although they're all in the ball-park). Thank you. I upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

How about *precede* ?
For example, it's used for explaining relation among mathematical operators.., e.g., multiplication will precede summation..

Answer (score 1):

In legalese, we usually call these constitutional guarantees "inviolable".

in·vi·o·la·ble
inˈvīələbəl/
adjective
adjective: inviolable
    1.
    never to be broken, infringed, or dishonored.

**Human rights are *inviolable*, you can make whatever laws you want so long as it doesn't violate one.**

By the way, this sentence is not a valid interpretation of human rights litigation or *stare decisis*.

Comment: I like how this was thumbed down in less than 10 seconds from my post.  I am an Esquire in three states, by the way.

Comment: yeah, this place is like that. That was a useful answer. I'm looking for a verb, basically something equivalent to 'trump', but I don't want to use the bridge analogy.